# Is there a way of accessing the second line of the dropdown list in vba?

Tags: html, excel, vba, ms-office

I am currently working on a VBA project on a website. Here is a screenshot of the part of the website i am interested in.

[image]

I basically have to write a vba code that selects the second row of this dropdown list. 
I wrote this piece of code

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim title As Variant
Set title = ie.getElementsByClassName("chosen-single")(3)
```

This code is actually refering to the correct part of the website because when i run these commands

```
MsgBox title.innerText
MsgBox title.innerHTML
```

I respectively get "Current" and the html of this part.

However, I am having trouble clicking on the second line of this dropdown menu. I do not want to access it by using the innerText "2019/07/31" because this date will constantly be changing. I just want to access the **second element of the list** always.

Can anyone help me with that?

Here is a snapshot of the HTML code of this webpage in case it helps:

[image]

Thank you so much!!

Comment: You are not making it easy. `tite` is referring to a div in the document but it appears that you want to select an option from a select list.    Posting the entire webpage or a download file would help you get the best answer.  I would start by opening the page in Chrome right click the element, click `Inspect`, right click the element in console hover over `Copy` in the menu and click `copy Selector`.  With some modification this selector string can be used with `document.querySelector()` to return the targeted element.